# Correct gutter installation to prevent ice dams?

Tags: gutters

[image: I]We had new guitars, downspouts and gutter guards installed and now there's a huge ice dam.

Should the downspout that collects water from upper levels be sitting in the valley?

The downspout empties into a lower gutter on our sun porch, which is in the NW area of the roof.

We live in Minnesota.

Comment: A properly insulated attic space keeps the snow from melting on the roof, that is the way to prevent ice dams.   see my answer to a similar question   -  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126759/how-do-i-prevent-ice-dams-from-forming-on-the-eaves-of-an-addition/126763#126763

Comment: It looks like the ice extends well above the downspout, all the way to the skylights, is that about right? So the water/ice could just be funneled to the same spot where the downspout happens to be also?

Comment: This doesn't look to me like it's related to the gutter since the ice is forming well above the gutter. I think @Alaskaman is correct in that there isn't enough insulation to prevent the ice damn.